# Error when trying to fit glmer in R with Poisson distribution: PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate

Tags: r, glm, poisson

The models I'm running won't converge / show an error. Do you have any advice about working with non-normal focal data? Most of the data are zero inflated or highly skewed.

The model I want to run is this (the response is just an example):

```
model <- glmer(Duration_behavior_1 ~ 
                 status * days_since_event +
                 focal_age + 
                 focal_rank +
                 pink +
                 year + 
                 hour +
                 (1|FocalID) + 
                 (1|partner.ID),
               family = 'poisson',
               offset = Focal_duration,
               data = data)
```

But I get this error:

```
Error in (function (fr, X, reTrms, family, nAGQ = 1L, verbose = 0L, maxit = 100L,  :
  (maxstephalfit) PIRLS step-halvings failed to reduce deviance in pwrssUpdate
```

I think the problem is the offset. If I remove it, I get this warning instead:

```
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.00252314 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue
 - Rescale variables?;Model is nearly unidentifiable: large eigenvalue ratio
 - Rescale variables?
```

But, of course, the offset is necessary to control for the duration of the observation...

Do you think it would be recommended to change the distribution to a negative binomial, instead of using a Poisson?

Answer (score 3):

You almost certainly want to use `log(Focal_duration)` as your offset, rather than `Focal_duration`.

Suppose `eta` is the linear predictor not including the offset, e.g. `beta0 + beta1*x1 + beta2*x2 + ...` (also including the components based on the random effect).  Then the predicted value is `eta + offset`, and the expected mean is `exp(eta)*exp(offset)`.  If the values of the offset (`Focal_duration`) are reasonably large (say, 60 seconds?), then the values of `exp(offset)` are huge (e.g. `exp(60)` ~ 1.1e26), which [besides being not what you want] messes up numerical computations.

In fact, the [GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#convergence-warnings) says something very similar:

> a common error is to specify an offset to a log-link model as a raw searching-effort value, i.e. `offset(effort)` rather than `offset(log(effort))`. While the intention is to fit a model where counts ∝ effort, specifying `offset(effort)` leads to a model where `counts ∝ exp(effort)` instead; `exp(effort)` is often a huge (and model-destabilizing) number.